# why my coroutine async only works inside a runBlocking?

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to understand coroutines and seems to be quite more difficult to understand than expected, maybe someone could give me the right approach for this.

I want to have an endpoint (simple hello world) that will call a suspended function.

For that Ive made this:

```
@GET
@Path("/test")
suspend fun test() : String {
    coroutineScope {
        async {
            doSomething()
        }.await()
    }
    return "Hello"
}
```

and at doSomething() I simple do this

```
private fun doSomething(){
   logger.info("request")
}
```

Seems pretty easy and straighforward, reading about async https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/composing-suspending-functions.html it needs a coroutine scope https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/async.html , so at my code should work.

but then when I call my method I get this:

```
! kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException: null
! at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.ContinuationImpl.getContext(ContinuationImpl.kt:105)
! at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScopeKt.coroutineScope(CoroutineScope.kt:179)
```

NPE on this

```
 public override val context: CoroutineContext
        get() = _context!!
```

when moving the `coroutineScope` for a `runBlocking` it works. Any idea what Im missing? how can I make this work? (Im trying to avoid using  `GlobalScope.async`)

I am using dropwizard as framework

Answer (score 0):

Don't make your controller function a suspend function. They can only be called from other suspend function or coroutines.

I don't know exactly how your endpoint gets built without errors, but since it is executed - there is **no coroutine context inside - because we didn't define any**! Thats why you get a NPE for the context.

BTW: The code below will have no asyncronous behaviour, because you await immediately - just like normal sequential code:

```
async {
    doSomething()
}.await()
```

---

To fix your problem fast, here how I would rewrite it:

```
@GET
@Path("/test")
fun test() : String {
    GlobalScope.launch { // Starts "fire-and-forget" coroutine
       doSomething() // It will execute this in separate coroutine 
    }
    return "Hello" // will be returned almost immediately 
}
```

To understand more about context, read [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html). **TLDR**: Use Kotlin's builders and functions to create a context - like `runBlocking`

---

**EDIT**

To avoid `GlobalScope.` functions, we can use `runBlocking`

```
@GET
@Path("/test")
fun test() : String = runBlocking {
    val deferredResult1 = async { doSomething() } // Starts immediately in separate coroutine
    val deferredResult2 = async { doSomethingElse() } // Starts immediately in separate coroutine

    logger.print("We got:${deferredResult1 .await()} and ${deferredResult2 .await()}")

    "Hello" // return value - when both async coroutines finished
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, is there any way I can avoid use GlobalScope?

Comment: Added another solution - a little extended to make the case realistic